# Downloading KDB tables into a [q] session from a web-facing database

Tags: kdb

What I have: the hostname/port number of an always-running [q] session that exposes several KDB tables via our internal web. I can easily run [q] commands against it in a browser (or even, through the use of [hopen], via a local [q] session invoked on the command line).

What I need: a [q] script, or the knowledge of how to write one, that will automatically connect to the web-facing database, and copy over all of its tables into the localhost [q] session's working memory (**without** knowing all the table names in advance).

Concerns include:

- The tables are huge. I'm prepared to wait on my machine if need be, but I do need this to work eventually.
- While I can get a legible list of all the server's table-names, I can never get it in a useful format (ideally it'd be a List, rather than the Symbol that the hopen-ed [tables] command always gives me). Also, I'm told that it may be possible to accomplish the transfers without ever explicitly querying the table names, though I can't imagine how; bonus points if you manage that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can implement smoething like this :

```
.data.oc:1000;

/connect to the session using hopen
h:hopen `::1234;

/get the table names
tabs:h"tables[]";

/create local tables with the same names
{ .[x;();:;()] } each tabs;

/for each table name
{[tab]

     /get the table count
    c:h({count value x};tab);

    oc:.data.oc;
    /cut the table count to some optimal value, say 10,000 (0-99999; 10000-19999).
    idxl:$[c>oc; [ l: c div  oc; ( (0;oc-1)+/:oc*til l),enlist (l*oc;c-1)  ] ; enlist (0; c-1)];

    /now iterate over the list and use them as indexes to query the table.
    {[t;idx] t upsert h ({[t;y] ?[t; enlist (within;`i;y);0b;()] } ; t;idx ) }[tab] each  idxl;

 }each tabs
```

Comment: Does this assume the tables are all in memory? What about on-disk/partitioned?

Comment: What exactly is the function of the last two lines in the for-each function? Those starting with [idxl] and [t;idx], I mean--the comments aren't enough for me to conceptually parse them.

Comment: Thanks, @terrylynch ; I forgot to highlight that in case of the partitioned table need to use the date clause first, will update the post.

Comment: Since the table is huge, we are splitting the total table count to small manageable value, and then at each remote call we are passing the indexes and upserting the data to the local table. Basically querying the data in chunks.